# Spring boot 4.2.7 Mail api Cannot find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for bean with name 'mailSender' defined in URL

Tags: spring, api, email, spring-boot

I am using spring boot 4.2.7 with mail API. all jars in class path and loaded correctly except mail related. I have context support and mai api jar in classpath. But always getting `classnotfoundexcpetion`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field: private
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.beanFactory;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for
bean with name 'mailSender' defined in URL
[file:/C:workspace_md5/abc/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml];
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
       ... 17 common frames omitted Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for
bean with name 'mailSender' defined in URL
[file:/C:/Users/guptra8/workspace_md5/asg/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml];
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1352)
~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the question I can see you are using spring boot, so just add below dependency in your project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And in application.properties add appropriate values to the below keys.

Below is the sample to add GMAIL as your mail sender

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.username=###@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=#####
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.timeout=2000
```

and then in your service class autowire JavaMailSender and you can use it.

Example implementation code is [here](https://github.com/rajadileepkolli/springsecuredthymeleafapp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/learning/securedapp/service/email/EmailService.java)

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet there is no class named org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImp on your classpath. Make sure you are creating beans only of existing classes.

If you are using eclipse, **You can verify this in .classpath file**

> .classpath
>
> Classpath specifies which Java source files and resource files in a
>   project are considered by the Java builder and specifies how to find
>   types outside of the project. The Java builder compiles the Java
>   source files into the output folder and also copies the resources into
>   it.